# how to run rm in background in terminal

Tags: command-line, background-process

I have the following command to delete files in a folder that are 15 days or older:

> find /var/www/App/app/var/sessions* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;

what is the best way to speed this up and run it on the background? I heard rm is a pretty slow operation

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the I/O priority of the operation. And you should not start one `rm` instance per file:

```
find /var/www/App/app/var/sessions* -mtime +15 -exec ionice -c3 rm {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Most modern versions of `find` support `-delete` as a parameter, so you won't be launching any more processes; just use that instead of the `-exec` string. Running it under `ionice` as well won't let it tie up the hard drive.